# Use input box to search database and show results on same page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm totally new to coding and I am trying to teach myself as I go along so don't judge me haha! I have a problem though. I have an HTML page that is putting information from input boxes into my MySQL Database.

I want to use another input box on my html page to show me data from my database on the same page. I'm not entirely sure on how to do this and this is where I need help.

Can anyone help me?

Here is what is on my html/php page:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Form</h1>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="Name" /><br><br>
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="Phone" /><br><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="Pass" /><br><br>

<input type="submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My database column names are:

Name
Phone
Pass

Sorry if i sound silly, I'm just trying to practice some different things :)

Comment: And so whats the issue you're having doing so? Just set it as a placeholder.

Comment: Come on now, do some research and show us what you've tried, we're here to help not do the work for you. Where are your sql statements / php code ?

Comment: All of the data? Or the data that was just submitted? Or entirely different data based on separate search criteria? If so, what is the search criteria you want to use?

Comment: Well the form is there to input into the database but I'm not sure how to then get the information back out from the database and show it on the same page. If you know what I mean.

Comment: In the `<input>` or just as text?

Comment: Also, are you unsure how to query the database to get the required info? Or are you unsure how to display the results once youve done so?

Comment: To show the row from the DB as text, maybe in a table or something. I have been trying different things and following some of things from the W3Schools website.

Comment: Post your SELECT query so we can see it

Comment: This is very, very basic, and the resources are out there. And i'm pretty sure they have something on W3schools covering this.

Comment: I have managed to get the information for each DB row to show in a table on the page using the W3School code. What I was wanting to know how to do was use an input box that I can use to search for a specific name and have it show up in a table. Like I said above, I'm new to all this so some of it I still don't understand yet, even if it is basic stuff. I'm still trying to learn it.

Comment: If you're listing all the information in a table, you can use jQuery plugins to search through the table.

Comment: Let me know if that's what you need http://jsfiddle.net/JohnGuan/ADMuh/

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you should retrieve data from your table. Use [PDO](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Data-Object/PDO-Tutorial-P842.html) or [MySqli](http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65) to communicate with your sql server. You can write the php code before the attached html. Don't forget databases have not columns, only tables have, which are in the dbs... so look MySql doc in w3 (at least).
2. If you got your data, you can put it to your 'input box' by inserting php code to the 'value' attribute of the  field - use i.e. the [echo](http://hu1.php.net/echo) statement.
3. I assumed you've already inserted your data to your db, and/or have the proper code for that.

I hope I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just query the database for the name you need as opposed to everything and grab the name youre searching from your form.

```
$name = $_POST['search'];
$query = "SELECT Name, Phone, Pass FROM table WHERE Name = '{$name}'";
```